# Bootstrap sidebar dynamic navigation with multiple sublevels (10)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, twitter-bootstrap-3

[SB Admin 2 free admin template](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html#)

I need to implement a sidebar navigation menu like in the link above, but dynamically using jQuery/KnockoutJS. By dynamic I mean the navigation is coming as JSON from a WEB API REST service in the following format:

```js
   [
{
    "label": "Home Page",
    "iconClasses": "fa fa-home",
    "url": "#"
},
{
    "label": "Tasks",
    "iconClasses": "fa fa-th-large",
    "children": [
        {
            "label": "My Tasks",
            "iconClasses": "fa fa-tasks",
            "url": "#"
        },
        {
            "label": "All Tasks",
            "iconClasses": "fa fa-tasks",
            "url": "#"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "label": "Multilevel Menu",
    "iconClasses": "fa fa-sitemap",
    "children": [
        {
            "label": "Menu Item 1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Menu Item 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Menu Item 2"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Menu Item 2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "Menu Item 3"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Menu Item 3",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": "and so forth..."
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The top menu have a iconClasses where is mentioned the font awesome icon classes.

The menu should have the functionality like the link example menu:

- when you are on a specific page that menu should be selected as `active` or `current`
- if the current page is a sub menu from the tree, the tree should be open.
- if the tree is open and you select another branch menu from another tree then the opened tree should collapse.

P.S.  Here's JSFiddle trial [trial](http://jsfiddle.net/jwbxbv9t/)

Comment: This looks more like a specification for someone to write code for you. Where is your code that shows an attempt to create this? SO isn't a code writing factory where you just order up what you need

Comment: I'll post soon a jsfiddle trial ... doing something right now! NO I don't want somebody to write it for me but an advise to follow, cause this is a new thing for me ...

Comment: not done in knockout but here's example of recursive menu function done in jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/kt2her9b/1 ... might help

Comment: Doesn't look hard at all ...

Comment: I managed in knockout to show the top option but without the tree ... http://jsfiddle.net/djwzbLbx/

Comment: Updated your example to render child nodes.  http://jsfiddle.net/djwzbLbx/1/

Comment: So basically what you did is wrapping that line within `<!-- ko if:$data.children -->`

Comment: Works fine! Can you add an answer so I will mark it as correct? Thanks!